# A question about a step in the proof of $(A\cap B)^\circ$ $=$ $A^\circ\cap B^\circ$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing

I was trying to prove this proposition. I don't have any problem in the first inclusion, but got stuck at some point in the second:

My proof of the second inclusion:

Take $x\in  A^\circ \cap B^\circ$, then $x\in A^\circ$ and $x\in B^\circ$, then $x$ is an interior point of both $A$ and $B$, so $\exists \epsilon,\delta>0$, such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset A$ and $B(x, \delta) \subset B$, then $ B( x, \gamma)$ $=$ $B(x, \epsilon) \cap B(x, \delta)$ $\subset A\cap B$ and so $x$ is an interior point in $A\cap B$ that means $x\in$ $(A\cap B)^\circ$.

My question here is that: Is $\gamma$ $=$ $min(\epsilon, \delta)$ since we are talking about a "ball"?

Comment: You have to _define_ $\gamma$. But yes, if you set $\gamma = \min(\epsilon,\delta)$, the argument works.

Comment: Also, you should specify, in your question, that the space in question is a metric space. The result is true in the more general context of a topological space, but then your argument would need to adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct, after you specify that $\gamma=\min\{\varepsilon,\delta\}$, since, under that assumption$$B(x,\gamma)\subset B(x,\varepsilon)\cap B(x,\delta)\subset A\cap B.$$

Note that your argument nearly works for *topological* spaces. Let $V_A$ be a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $A$ and let $V_B$ be a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $B$. Define $V$ as $V_A\cap V_B$. Then $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $A\cap B$.